# Catalpa leaves drooping. Is it from too much rain or something more?

Tags: trees

I have a five year old Northern Catalpa in my yard, zone 4B. Earlier in the summer and in prior years the leaves were held more erect, but now they are all drooping. We have had a lot of rain this summer, and in fact are under a flash-flood warning at the moment. When I compare my catalpa to other (full-grown) catalpas in the area, though, I do not see the same droop in the leaves of the other trees that I see in mine.

Other things to know about my tree:

- When it was 2 years old, it did have a small (~1/16") hole in the trunk, through which I noticed small ants entering the tree. This area has completely healed over, but I've always been a bit worried about it.
- It does have some old, healed over weed whacker damage at the base of the trunk (photo below).
- I have a major, major infestation of Japanese Beetles in my yard this year, and there have been some beetles in the tree, although I have not noticed the damage in the catalpa that I've seen in other trees in my yard.
- Soil in the area is clay and alkaline.

So my questions are:

1. Does this look consistent with a tree that has simply been overwatered? Or should I be worried about something else?
2. If it is overwatering, are there any steps I can take to help the tree, given that I've done no supplemental watering at all this summer?

[image: Catalpa - full view]

[image: Leaf close up 1]

[image: Leaf close up 2]

[image: Old trunk damage]

Comment: It's looking likely that the drooping was an early sign of verticillium wilt. Two branches have now started exhibiting yellow/brown leaves and twig samples taken today showed black streaking. I will update when results come back from university extension lab.

Comment: Hi michelle! I know it's been a number of months, but I was wondering how your tree is doing. What did the lab results say? Is there an update you'd like to give us? An edit to the question would be fine, but if you have something that could work as an answer, that would help people, and also get this question out of the "unanswered" group! This is a beautiful tree, and I hope it's doing well.

Comment: Unfortunately the lab I sent the sample to was no longer in operation. I was given contact info for a different lab, but never got around to sending in a sample. It did not improve before losing its leaves in fall. It's been dormant all winter, so I am still waiting to see what it looks like when it wakes up. usually that happens in May here.

Comment: Thanks for letting us know! Hopefully when the spring comes it will perk up!